# Is there an umbrella that can be used for photography and also for protection from the elements?

Tags: umbrella

Is there an umbrella that can be used as a shoot through and something for protection from the elements?

I mean something whose handle can be removed so that the umbrella can be fixed to a light stand for a shoot.

Comment: It's just occurred to me that you are asking for an *umbrella* recommendation, not a "how to attach it" recommendation. But why wouldn't you just use a white umbrella to shoot through, and why would the handle need to be removed?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just new to shooting so was not aware of the different mounts and clamps that I can use to solve for it. Thanks for your answer!! It makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen a dual-purpose umbrella like you describe, but a solution should be pretty easy to create. What pops into mind are [Ram Mounts](http://www.rammount.com): you could combine a pair of [Tough-Claws](http://www.rammount.com/products/toughclaw) or [Yoke Clamps](http://www.rammount.com/part/RAM-B-121BU) with a socket arm.

[image: Tough-Claw]
[image: Yoke Clamp]

Looking at more traditional photography options, [a search at B&H for clamps](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Clamps/ci/1353/N/4062040374?origSearch=clamp) turns up a number of results including this [Super Clamp](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/824360-REG/impact_cc_106r_super_clamp_with_ratchet.html):

[image: Super Clamp]

Comment: The superclamp is pretty great. The price seems high, but they're well-made and will last forever.

Answer (score 1):

Take a rain umbrella made from sheer white material or recover a frame with suitable cloth.  That might not be *great* for shooting through since caussy material is not waterproof and stuff you find at the fabric store is not white balanced for optical quality, but you can adjust white balance if close enough.

Cut off the handle and attach a 1/4-inch threaded insert in the stub. Attach a *hanger bolt* to the handle: it's a wood screw on one end and a machine screw on the other.  Add a ring of rubber glued on the handle so you can screw it snug without it being *tight*.  Now you can unscrew the handle and screw on a common mount.

*but*, umbrellas don't get mounted... the mount holds the light *and* has a hole for the umbrella handle to pass through.  These are very thin shafts and would not stand up to wind or rough handling.

So really you would need to build an umbrella with a sturdy steel rod that's slim enough to use with the light but still strong enough; or have the common flimsy hollow rod replaced or sheathed.  How about drilling a hole down the length of a nice oak dowel or a cane, and slide the photo umbrella handle into that?  A screw on the side would clamp it.

You would still need the fabric part to handle both purposes.

Reflective would be more doable. Take a heavy black rain umbrella and line it with somem reflective material, like they make folding reflectors from.  I picked up a cheap "space blanket" on sale to use to make custom reflectors, but that's truely shiny not matte.